# Is every submodule of an injective module injective?

Tags: injective-module

I don't think this is the case but I can't find an error in my proof:

Let $N \subset M$ be a submodule of an injective module $M$. Suppose we have maps $f:A \to N$ and $h:A \to B$ and we want to prove that there is some map $g:B \to N$ so that $g \circ h = f$.

Since $M$ is injective consider the induced map $f' : A \to M$. Then there must exist $g':B \to M$ so that $g' \circ h = f'$. But the range of $f'$ is $N$, so that range of $g'$ must be $N$ and thus $g'$ is the desired map.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is injective (it's [uniquely] divisible) - but 'the' submodule $\mathbb Z$ is not.

Comment: BTW, you didn't write it, but I am assuming that you meant $h$ to be injective? Also  $F'$ should be $f'$.

Comment: There's a famous theorem to the effect that every $R$-module is isomorphic to a submodule of an injective $R$-module.

Comment: There's no reason why $g'(B)\subseteq N$.

Comment: Well it has to agree with $f'$, and $f'(A) \subset N$. I don't follow.

Comment: Counter-example: Take $A=B=N ={\mathbb Z}$, $M={\mathbb Q}$, with $h$ multiplication by $2$, and $f$ the identity. If your extension $g'$ had image in $N$, then $1/2\in N$.

Comment: @mtheorylord have you understood the counterexample? something that is seeming obviously true to you is not right: in this example $g'(B)\not \subset N$.

Comment: Oh, ok I get it.